# to find submit function return error or not in html5

Tags: jquery, html

I put html5 validation in my web page.

```
<form class="" id="myForm" method="post" action="#" >
<input type="text"  required />
<input type="submit" /> </form>
<div> <input type="button" id="myButton" /></div>
```

I added validation for my form in jquery.I have functioned like this

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $("#myForm").click();
//myNewfunction
});
```

So the fields are validating properly.But the problem is myNewfunction executing when the form firing error also .How to prevent that.If form is not correct myNewfunction should not execute also my validation should work simultaneously

Thanks

Comment: why you fire click event on form, and why don't you use submit event?

Comment: I have my click button out of form.The reason is i hidden my submit button and triggering externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML5 `checkValidity` method of FORM, e.g:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    if(!$("#myForm")[0].checkValidity()) return;

    $("#myForm").submit();
    // or call: myNewfunction();
});
```

BTW, don't trigger click event of FORM which by default does nothing, instead, submit the FORM.

Comment: The purpose of checkValidity method is to check for required fields, so it must work just as here: http://jsfiddle.net/sr5Fu/

Comment: please click the button..the validation is not working

Comment: Ha ok, I understood what you mean but then just trigger submit click: http://jsfiddle.net/sr5Fu/1/   `$("#myForm").find(':submit').click();`

Comment: Its not working.both executing same time.please check it jsfiddle.net/sr5Fu/1

Comment: Both what? Clicking on `#myButton` shouldn't submit the FORM if not valid. Now think about providing a jsfiddle which replicates your issue... As i see it, the jsfiddle i provided works. So is this jsfiddle works as expected for you? If not, tell us what do you expect

Comment: i updated the code . Click "click here" button . if the form is valid it should show alert "test" otherwise it should show only validation message as "please fill out this field" alone.Why am telling is if the form is not valid it should not trigger the next line

Comment: @Gauti where is the updated code??? http://jsfiddle.net/sr5Fu/4/??? If ya, why not add it in your comment?! And really, to find a workaround using jsfiddle and answer provided, take only few seconds... You should show a minimum effort to resolve your own issue, not waiting other to solve it... See: http://jsfiddle.net/sr5Fu/5/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47239/discussion-between-gauti-and-a-wolff)

Answer (score 0):

Your way:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    if(validatemyform()){// form succesfully validated
        $("#myForm").submit(); // submit manually (not needed), it does it anyway when not returning false
    } else {
        return false; //don't submit form
    }
});
```

A cleaner example of validating a form:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    return validatemyform();
});
```

Your validation function:

```
function validatemyform(){
   ...
   return true; //when validated
   ...
   return false; // when not
}
```